# Vim Open file in multi split modes

Tags: vim

I want to open 3 files in multiple split mode. For example let's say I have 3 files `file1 file2 file3`
I want to open `file1` & `file2` in vertical split mode , and both of the vertical split must be in horizontal split with `file3`.

```
vim file1 file2 -O file3 -o
```

I tried above code , but it overrides the last `-O` by `-o` for all 3 files.

Comment: please refer  <b>http://superuser.com/questions/486532/how-to-open-files-in-vertically-horizontal-split-windows-in-vim-from-the-command</b>

Comment: @Muralibabud  I am unable to form it in form a command as per above post

Comment: how about `vim -o file1.txt -O file2.txt -O file3.txt` ? 

`-o is like :split, -O is like :vsplit`

Answer (score 7):

`-o`, `-O`, and `-p` are mutually exclusive. You can't combine them.

From `main.c`, `command_line_scan()`:

```
case 'p':           /* "-p[N]" open N tab pages */
    parmp->window_layout = WIN_TABS;
    break;
case 'o':           /* "-o[N]" open N horizontal split windows */
    parmp->window_layout = WIN_HOR;
    break; 
case 'O':       /* "-O[N]" open N vertical split windows */
    parmp->window_layout = WIN_VER;
    break;
```

and then in `create_windows()`:

```
parmp->window_count = make_windows(parmp->window_count,
    parmp->window_layout == WIN_VER);
```

And `make_windows()` from `window.c`:

```
/*
* Make "count" windows on the screen.
* Return actual number of windows on the screen.
* Must be called when there is just one window, filling the whole screen
* (excluding the command line).
*/
int
make_windows(count, vertical)
    int         count;
    int         vertical UNUSED;  /* split windows vertically if TRUE */
{
    int         maxcount;
    int         todo;
```

As you see, there is no facility to say "split those few windows horizontally, and those few vertically".

The easiest way to do what you want is using `-c` to send "direct" commands to Vim:

```
vim main.c -c ':split gui.c' -c ':vsplit window.c'
```

Which can be abbreviated to:

```
vim main.c -c 'sp gui.c | vs window.c'
```